# Get the value of an object and assign with index using for loop PHP

Tags: php

I have a data passed from javascript and I want to assign into PHP variables with an index.

The result of `var_dump($data)` is this:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (5) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(2)
  ["item_id0"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["quantity0"]=>
  int(1)
  ["item_id1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["quantity1"]=>
  int(2)
}
```

**PHP Code but not working**

The error is in line of `$item_id[$i] = $data->item_id[$i]; $quantity[$i] = $data->quantity[$i];`

Error output something like this: `Undefined property: stdClass::$item_id`

It seems that in `$data->item_id[$i]` part, the `item_id[$i]` is not equal as `item_id0`, which I am expecting to be.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$length = $data->length;

for($i=0; $i<=$length; $i++){

$item_id[$i] = $data->item_id[$i];
$quantity[$i] = $data->quantity[$i];

$sql = "INSERT INTO transaction_details(item_id, quantity) VALUES(:item_id, :quantity)";

try {
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(':item_id', $item_id[$i]);
  $stmt->bindParam(':quantity', $quantity[$i]);

  $stmt->execute();

  echo '{"notice": {"text": "Transaction Added"}';
}
```

Comment: `item_id` property is not __array__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
${"item_id$i"} // is same as $item_id0 or $item_id1
```

So your code should be:

```
${"item_id$i"} = $data->{"item_id$i"};
//now you can echo like below:
echo $item_id0; // or even: echo $item_id1
```

Comment: I didn't aware of variable variables. You are a life saver.